# clojure macro if-empty?

Tags: macros, clojure

I have written a if-pred? macro as follows

```
(defmacro if-pred?
  ([pred lst then] `(if (~pred ~lst) ~then nil))
  ([pred lst then else] `(if (~pred ~lst) ~then ~else)))
```

Now I want to construct a if-empty? macro from that.

```
(defmacro if-empty? [lst then & else] 
  (if-pred? empty? lst then else))
```

I want to use if-empty? like:

```
(if-empty? '()
       (println "empty")
       (println "not-empty"))
```

But apparently if-empty? is not working. When I run the above code **not-empty** gets printed immaterial of whether the list I pass to if-empty? is really empty or not. After printing  **not-empty** java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not quoting the expansion of (defmacro if-empty? ...), and you're forcing the optional else argument into a list.

```
(defmacro if-empty? 
  ([lst then else] 
    `(if-pred? empty? ~lst ~then ~else))
  ([lst then] 
    `(if-pred? empty? ~lst ~then)))
```

Comment: Because my if-pred? macro handles optional arguments (else) is there any way for me to have just one type of argument list here instead of two?

Comment: you can do the & else argument and test if the list contains any items in the non-quoted part of the macro body, but I think it's not going to be clearer if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Macros need to return code. Try this:

```
(defmacro if-empty? [lst then & else] 
    `(if-pred? empty? ~lst ~then ~@else))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your if-empty? macro.  You forgot to backtick the body.  Should be:

```
(defmacro if-empty? [lst then & else]
  `(if-pred? empty? ~lst ~then ~else))
```

Comment: Works if the list is empty but doesn't work otherwise. Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: I don't think quotes is the issue. I am able to modify Joost's code and make it work without backtick

Comment: I think it is.  Here's the macroexpand of your code: ((println "not-empty")).  Here it is after adding the backtick & ~: (user/if-pred? clojure.core/empty? '() (println "empty") nil)

Comment: After making the changes that you have suggested `(macroexpand-1 '(if-empty? (range 10) (println "empty") (println "not-empty")))` becomes `(on_lisp.utility/if-pred? clojure.core/empty? (range 10) (println "empty") ((println "not-empty")))`. Any idea why I am getting an extra parentheses in the else part?

Comment: Because the else is optional it sucks up any extra parameters passed to the function and puts them in a list.  You can destructure it like this: [lst then & [else]]  That should get rid of the extra parens.

Answer (score 0):

As the macro `if-empty?` has different signature from `if-pred?` with the variable arity of the else part it needs a `do` block to function correctly.

your `if-empty?` macro has a few problems, first it's not back-quoted which will cause

So if you need the `if-empty?` to work so that it will evaluate single expression if the given sequence is empty and several ones if the sequence is not empty following macro should work:

```
(defmacro if-empty? [lst then & else] `(if-pred? empty? ~lst ~then (do ~@else)))
```

If the the & before args was an accident following should work:

```
(defmacro if-empty? [lst then else] `(if-pred? empty? ~lst ~then ~else))
```

As a side note as these macro's arent predicates i wouldn't use the ? in the end of their name.